# If $n < \aleph^*(m)$, then $n < 2^m$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Without $AC$

Let  $\aleph^*(m)$ be the least aleph that $\not\leq^* m$. I need a help or hint that if $n < \aleph^*(m)$, then $n < 2^m$.

$a \leq^* b$ means we can define a surjective map from $b$ onto $a$.

Comment: In the definition you need to require explicitly that $a$ might be empty as well.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT:** If there is a surjection from $A$ onto $B$, then there is an injection from $B$ into $\mathcal P(A)$. This leaves the case where $n=0$, but that's easy.

Comment: I'd be ecstatic to hear any form of criticism along with that downvote. Even "I dislike the user".

Comment: I don't get it either, so here's a +1 to (somewhat) balance it out.

Answer (score 0):

Is my proof true?  I suppose that $n = 2^m$. Then $m < n$ and so $m <^* n$. From $m <^* n$ and $n \leq^* m$, $m <^* m$, a contradiction.

Comment: How does $n\not = 2^m$ imply that $n < 2^m$?

Comment: Since $m < 2^m$

Comment: You can't quite use comparability here, since the axiom of choice is itself equivalent to saying that any two cardinals are comparable (either order works for the proof, $<$ or $<^*$). Instead take an arbitrary $n<\aleph^*(m)$, then use the definition of $\aleph^*(m)$ to infer some relationship between $n$ and $m$, and finally use my hint.